# how to access json data os asyncStorage function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using AsyncStorage to store data. Here is my function of storing data :

```
const profile = { userId, name, email  };

         await AsyncStorage.setItem('userProf', JSON.stringify(profile));
```

I have a problem when I try to access the data , if I console.log:

```
  async componentWillMount(){
     const profile = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userProf');

     console.log(profile);
   }
```

> {"userId":"jefla3E0tjcJHhHKJK45QoIinB2","name":"egfgege","email":"ergeg@egrge.com"}

Now if I am willing to get only email value , I have tried with:

> console.log(profile.email);
>
> console.log(profile[0].email);

None of them worked, I get undefined as output, could you please help.

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.parse(profile).email);`. The data is stored as a plain string, so you will need to parse it as an object to access its properties.

Comment: try `profile[email]` and if that a nested objects then try `profile[0][email]`

Comment: thanks @Peraka Sola , it worked.

Comment: According to the documentation, the value [`getItem`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#getitem) gives you is a **string** (like with web storage). You're not parsing the string.

Answer (score 4):

As AsyncStorage take and returns a string you will need to parse the string into json. You're already using `JSON.stringify` to save your object, you need to do the reverse operation to get it back to being an object.

```
const savedProfile = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userProf');
const profile = JSON.parse(savedProfile);
```

Then you should be able to access it the properties as you normally would, for example

```
const userId = profile.userId;
const email = profile.email;
const name = profile.name;
```

You may want to make sure that you perform a check that the returned value from AsyncStorage isn't null, as that will cause problems for you. Also `await` functions can throw, so you should make sure that you wrap your call to AsyncStorage in a `try/catch`

```
async componentWillMount(){
  try {
    const savedProfile = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userProf');
    // you should check that the savedProfile is not null here
    const profile = JSON.parse(savedProfile);
    const userId = profile.userId;
    const email = profile.email;
    const name = profile.name;
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
  console.log(profile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When storing the value with `AsyncStorage.setItem( ... )`, you use `JSON.stringify` to convert the complete object into a `String`. This means, if you want to have a "normal" `Object` back (to use the dot operator), you have to use `JSON.parse`:

```
const profile = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userProf');
console.log(JSON.parse(profile));
```